# python selenium alternative for web actions

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, automation, bots

I am constantly waiting for the page to load in web actions. Is there a way to do web actions faster without waiting for the page to load ?

When working with Selenium, it takes time to navigate from page to page.

Answer (score 0):

If your use case does not require opening an actual browser and interacting with the webpage through simulated user input, then you can use HTTP requests to extract/manipulate data from the page. Popular modules for this are Requests and BeautifulSoup.